# how to make scan and order 0, when sorting on multikeys

Tags: php, mongodb

I have bunch of documents on mongodb, and this is a dummy insert

```
 array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("51a449866803fa680a000002"),
  'a' => 'dweddwe',
  'b' => 'asdasdad',
  'c' => 
  array (
    '0' => 'car',
  ),
  'u' => '1',
  'x' => 
  array (
   '0' => '51a0c0356803fa890a000003',
   '1' => '51a0c0356803fa890a000003',
  ),
  'y' => 'merto',
)
```

I have more than 100 inserted documents in my mongo database, the problem is, when I use this code and index like this `x_1__id_1` or in any other ways, I always get `[scanAndOrder] => 1`, I have no idea what might be the problem or solution, how can I sort it in an efficient way ? thank you :)

```
$m->cars->post->find(array("x" => array('$in' => $mendor["t"])))->limit(10)->sort(array("_id" => -1))->explain();
```

this is $mendor["t"],

```
't' => 
  array (
   '0' => '519f2de16803fabd0d000001',
   '1' => '51a0bf996803fa890a000001',
   '2' => '519f2db96803fad20d000001',
   '3' => '519f1cc56803fa960d000001',
 ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compund indexes are not useable for reverse ordering, but have no worries about it will not help in this case probably if you have in $mendor["t"] a real list. 
I made a test collection called t with simple documents like :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a4c2c75e0733e8428ab2c0"), "x" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a4c2c95e0733e8428ab2c1"), "x" : [ 1, 2, 3, 6 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a4c2cd5e0733e8428ab2c2"), "x" : [ 1, 4, 3, 6 ] }
```

I created the index : x_1__id_1

For the query:

```
db.t.find({x:3}).hint("x_1__id_1").sort({_id:1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor x_1__id_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 14,
    "nscannedObjects" : 14,
    "nscanned" : 14,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 14,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 14,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "x" : [
            [
                3,
                3
            ]
        ],
        "_id" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : ""
}
```

So it works as you like your query to work but :

```
db.t.find({x:{$in:[3,4]}}).hint("x_1__id_1").sort({_id:1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor x_1__id_1 multi",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 16,
    "nscannedObjects" : 28,
    "nscanned" : 28,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 28,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 28,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "x" : [
            [
                3,
                3
            ],
            [
                4,
                4
            ]
        ],
        "_id" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : ""
}
```

This is sort of reasonable while the multikey index which is used, is store as separated index keys the values in the array. See documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#multikey-indexes

So the different parts which where collected from the different keys will be merged by the engine and than sorted. If you use a criteria which is like my first query,so instead of an array just search for one value. Than it will scanAndOrder : false. Probably you have to make an  x_1_*id*-1 index.

There is a workaround but it is ugly a bit. If you use an or clause for the query than every part of the or list will use separately an index usage. So instead of using the in:[] condition, use or:[] and define as many different queries as many values you have in your $mendor["t"]  array. In mongoshell did not worked, but i am sure it should, maybe i missed something.

Comment: how can i merge keys ? and how can i add a sorting phase ? thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Sorry i was missleading. There is no way to make what you like to. I just liked to write with this merge thing that it will be done by the database engine and it will not be able to use an index for sorting, if you use $in with an array longer than 1 element. I edit my answer according to this.

Comment: okay, this is bad for me :) but thank you, your explanation was nice :)

Comment: lets say I have 500 values, will or be a problem ?, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: $or does not sort by _id :) I will do it in another schema and try to change it

Comment: hiiiiii :) I reported a bug :) and I opened my topic under azure :)) this one is resolved, here is the link for you,[link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/AZURE-120?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel)

Answer (score 0):

You have a compound index on x, _id. The ordering of the _id is not absolute but within the context of an x value. In your query you are selecting a set of documents for particular x values and then ordering by just _id. So to get you the order it has to actually sort the results based on _id values as opposed to just using index order. That is what you see scan and order to be true. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok but how it differs from the situation when you have a range based query? This also shown the same phenomenon. I guess for the same reason. Does mongo utilize that the _ids are in ordered parts, or just sorting them without any assumption?